# Apache flink - PartitionNotFoundException

Tags: apache-flink

We are running a 5 node flink cluster over kubernetes and azure(8 gb ram each and total of 40 slots). We are running four jobs, all consuming data from kafka (each on a differnt consumer group). 
Few days ago, as our data load increased, weve moved our producer to produce data over 5 kafka partitions and the jobs parallelism to 5. 
Since then we're getting, every now and again (every hour on avg) the following exception on one of our task managers:

```
NFO|N||-|||Flink-4jc| 2019-01-22 16:00:32,032 Task:917 - org=[] - Map (2/5) (949a8349e7bdcf3fe3b8f992f52d249c) switched from RUNNING to FAILED.
org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.partition.PartitionNotFoundException: Partition 86656e59799eb529f24bac704ea06790@b1955e1a072e3b2f9e1f969fea509841 not found.
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.partition.consumer.RemoteInputChannel.failPartitionRequest(RemoteInputChannel.java:273)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.partition.consumer.RemoteInputChannel.retriggerSubpartitionRequest(RemoteInputChannel.java:182)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.partition.consumer.SingleInputGate.retriggerPartitionRequest(SingleInputGate.java:400)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.onPartitionStateUpdate(Task.java:1293)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.lambda$triggerPartitionProducerStateCheck$1(Task.java:1150)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:760)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:736)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Completion.run(CompletableFuture.java:442)
        at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:39)
        at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:415)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

The exception happens on different tasks and on different jobs.
I have read the following thread:
http://apache-flink-user-mailing-list-archive.2336050.n4.nabble.com/PartitionNotFoundException-when-running-in-yarn-session-td16081.html
Which gives me some hints of what might cause the exception, but i still can't figure out what's causing it in my case (increasing timeouts and network buffer size didn't help, and i couldn't understand why the jar file size matters)

Can anyone steer me to any direction on how to investigate what's happening, what logs should i open, what configuration to change etc?
If any other details are needed, I'll be happy to supply them.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you share with us the cluster entrypoint/jobmanager logs? Ideally on DEBUG log level.

Answer (score -1):

That maybe yours nodes' net card is fulled

Comment: This should be considered as comment, not the answer